# Validation on texbox. regulaexpression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

in my webapplication i have user registration page, in that one textbox contain House No: 
user has to enter houseno in that textbox. i that user can enter all numarics or all alphabets or all alphanumarics but not all special characters how can i restrict the user not to enter all special characters like 
user can enter

123455  or
abcdef  or
12abcdef

but not

&&&&&& or

or

@@@@ or
***** user should not enter the specail charecters
give me some solution thank u

Answer (score 1):

simply `^\w+$`

- `^` indicates the start of the string the regex pattern is applied to
- `\w` matches letters, digits and underscores.
- `+` matches one or more occurrences (in this case applied to letters, digits and underscores)
- `$` indicates the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to

If you didn't want underscores matched then

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

If the field was optional, then you may want to use `*` in place of `+` as this matches zero or more occurrences.

Comment: Hi Mr. Russ Cam it restriing to not use all special characters but for exmple i enter like this  "H-No : 41-259#" it gives error but i want to enter one specail charecters like this, i think u understand my problem other wise i will explain again thank u for response

Comment: i can enter specail charecters but not all for example if i enter in the text box like this "***&&&^^%%" it should gives error because it can't be a house no is in tit? thank u for response

Comment: i try that ^\w+$ not working i mean when i enter in the textbox like this "41-259#" it is giving error, but i want to allow that one thank you for response

Comment: which special characters **do you want to allow**?

Comment: Given your comment, change the regular expression to `^[\w-#]+$`

Comment: `[\w-#]`? Surely you mean `[\w#]`.

Comment: @Roger - Either `[\w#]` or `^[\w-#]+$` will work for input `41-259#`, but they are not finding the same matches. Try it out in Firebug for JavaScript of using NRegex (http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx) for C# regular expressions. `[\w#]` will not match the hyphen

Comment: @Russ: I'm surprised it works, `[\w-#]` looks like an invalid character range.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the regular expression you need is `(\w|\d)+`

**EDIT**: \w already includes digits, so: `\w+`

Comment: This would match true if there was one non-special character.  It wouldn't limit the input to only non-special characters.

Comment: Hi Mr. Konamiman Cam it restriing to not use all special characters but for exmple i enter like this "H-No : 41-259#" it gives error but i want to enter one specail charecters like this, i think u understand my problem other wise i will explain again thank u for response

Comment: i can enter specail charecters but not all for example if i enter in the text box like this "***&&&^^%%" it should gives error because it can't be a house no is in tit? thank u for response

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to achieve this in asp.net is to use a RegularExpressionValidator control. A simple example is as follows:

```
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="HouseNoLabel" Text="House No." AssociatedControlID="HouseNoTextBox" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="HouseNoTextBox" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="HouseNoValidator" ControlToValidate="HouseNoTextBox"
    ErrorMessage="* only alphanumeric characters are allowed" ValidationExpression="[\w]+" />
```

If you would like to stop a user from entering invalid values altogether, take a look at the MaskedEdit control from the Ajax Toolkit http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/

Comment: Mr.rob thank you for response but it is not working see it is allowing only alpha numarics but not special character like "41-259#" then it is giving error i said not all special character but combination of alphanumarics and specail characters allowed